# How to check if same files with other extensions are in a folder

Tags: file, shell, if-statement, video, equivalent

I have a folder with a lot of videos and thumbnails for the videos. After watching the video on Plex I delete it on the Web interface. So the thumbnails from the files stay in the folder.

Now i want to write a program that deletes all thumbnails, if there is no equivalent mp4 file.

Here is an example from "ls" of the folder:

PietSmiet - BATTLEFIELD HARDLINE 1920x1080.jpg

PietSmiet - CITIES SKYLINES # 45 1920x1080.jpg

PietSmiet - GTA ONLINE # 89 1920x1080.jpg

PietSmiet - MEIN ARSCH BRICHT AUS  1920x1080.jpg

PietSmiet - MINECRAFT Adventure Map # 92 1920x1080.jpg

PietSmiet - TTT # 171 1920x1080.jpg

PietSmiet - TTT # 171 1920x1080.mp4

Comment: "i iwant to write a program". Tell us what you have tried, S.O. isn't a free programming service. Good luck.

Comment: I have tried to get the filenames with "ls" then remove the extensions, so i have a list of all filenames in there.
After that i wanted to check if there are two euqal files and delete the others.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this would be to filter a *sorted* list through a script that does this:

- for each filename, make a copy of its name, trimming off the suffix
- compare that trimmed name with the trimmed name from the previous line (ignoring the case of the first line)
- if the two are equal, report the two filenames
- save the current filename (and trimmed filename) for the next comparison

That can have some repeated lines - which you could handle in the script.  But even simpler would be to pipe the result through `uniq`.  Also, I would override the locale to POSIX to get rid of the sometimes bizarre collating sequences which can equate upper/lowercase (and complicate the comparison).

In the POSIX shell, that would be two scripts, e.g, one to accept a file containing a list of filenames:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset LANG
unset LC_ALL
unset LC_CTYPE
sort $* | my-filter | uniq
```

and the `my-filter` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
last_file=
last_trim=
while :
do
    read this_file
    [ -z "$this_file" ] && break
    this_trim=$(echo "$this_file" | sed -e 's/\.[^.]*$//')
    if [ "$this_trim" = "$last_trim" ]
    then
            echo "$last_file"
            echo "$this_file"
    fi
    last_trim="$this_trim"
    last_file="$this_file"
done
```

Comment: So i have to make a shell script named start.sh with your first code and a second one named my-filter.sh. And start the start.sh script?

Comment: Yes - and give `start.sh` the name of a file containing the list of filenames you want to study.